# Android Navigation Component pop to transition issue

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have 2 actions

Action1

```
 <action
        android:id="@+id/actionBaseFragmentToAskForLocation"
        app:destination="@+id/introAskForLocationFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
```

Action2

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/actionIntroAskLocationToLogin"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/app_main_navigation" />
```

What i want is when the second action is triggered i want to clear the back stack and set only loginFragment to remain in the stack.

just one problem is when i perform the Action2, 'slide_out_right' is performed as exit animation

I understand that if we pop the fragment from the stack the 'popExitAnim' of action1 will be triggered instead of 'exitAnim' of action2.

but i want to know how can I make the fragment perform slide_out_left animation for exiting and also pop it out of the stack.

Comment: I've just come across the same problem - did you manage to fix it/work round it?

Comment: Seems it's a bug in the Navigation Component - I raised [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122892906) which turned out to be a duplicate of [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110433603).

Comment: okay man thanks for the information.

Comment: If you don't use animations, popUpTo works great. But with animations, I'm also seeing what you describe. If you specify a different popExitAnim for the action that gets popped as a result of popUpTo, you can sort of work around the problem. But then you end up breaking normal back button popping. So you can't win. I hope this is fixed soon.

Comment: Are the animations xml sets? I updated to 2.1.0 and now my enterAnims are flickering (alpha fade in + translation set). It appears to not like sets any more, alpha fade in on it's own is fine, translation on it's own is fine.

Comment: Any solution? Another problem now has occurred when navigating to an activity

Answer (score 11):

I ended up overriding `onCreateAnimation` in the fragment that calls `navigate`. This exemple shows how to navigate through nested nav graphs by ID and replace the **pop** exit animation (or `popExitAnim`) conditionnally.

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
    val navController = findNavController()
    val graph = navController.graph.findNode(R.id.onboardingGraph) as NavGraph
    val dest = graph.findNode(R.id.confirmationFragment)
    if (!enter && dest != null && navController.currentDestination?.id == dest.id) {
        return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left)
    }
    return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
}
```

Note that this particular situation is partly due to the directional nature of slide animations.

Comment: I have very limited knowledge about the state of the navigation library, but I think they must have fixed the issue internally, and the code in this answer can now **in some cases itself be problematic**. Creating and returning a custiom slide animation caused a screen flicker for me, that went away when I removed 
`public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {...}`

Answer (score 3):

This is bit of a tough one to solve due to `NavOptions` being internally handled by the convenience methods used in binding your drawer to the navigation graph. I originally tested this solution with the settings menu and `onOptionsItemSelected` but the basic idea should work here as well.

First, make sure your menu item IDs correspond to those of your navigation fragments:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...

    <item android:id="@+id/example_id" ... />
</menu>
```

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >

    ...

    <fragment android:id="@+id/example_id" ... />
</navigation>
```

Now, rather than using the ready-made methods for [connecting the drawer to your NavController](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) Implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in your NavHost activity and override the method `onNavigationItemSelected` like so:

```java
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    NavHost navHost = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.your_nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navHost);
}
```

This will forward the selection as a navigation in your graph. Replace `your_nav_host_fragment` with the fragment ID on which you set `app:defaultNavHost="true"`.

You will notice that while this works, it still defaults to the slide animations. This is because the [`NavigationUI` call internally creates its own `NavOptions`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java#74) with these settings:

```java
NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
                .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                .setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
                .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
                .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim);
```

Unfortunately the method does not yet take a `NavOptions.Builder` as an argument, but you can create an utility class based on the Android source code to mimic the functionality:

```java
public class NavigationUIHelper {
    public static boolean onNavDestinationSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item,
                                                   @NonNull NavController navController,
                                                   @NonNull NavOptions.Builder builder) {
        if ((item.getOrder() & Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY) == 0) {
            NavDestination destination = findStartDestination(navController.getGraph());
            builder.setPopUpTo(destination.getId(), false);
        }
        NavOptions options = builder.build();
        try {
            navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Need to copy this private method as well
    private static NavDestination findStartDestination(@NonNull NavGraph graph) {
        NavDestination startDestination = graph;
        while (startDestination instanceof NavGraph) {
            NavGraph parent = (NavGraph) startDestination;
            startDestination = parent.findNode(parent.getStartDestination());
        }
        return startDestination;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your activity you can now replace the call to NavigationUI with the one implemented in NavigationUIHelper:

```java
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    NavHost navHost = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.your_nav_host_fragment);
    NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
                .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
                .setEnterAnim(R.anim.custom_enter)
                .setExitAnim(R.anim.custom_exit)
                .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.custom_pop_enter)
                .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.custom_pop_exit);
    return NavigationUIHelper.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navHost, builder);
}
```

This should allow you to change the drawer transition animations according to your liking without having to replace the Navigation component.